# QGIS WMS Server : "Opening of authentication db FAILED"

Tags: qgis, postgresql, wms, qgis-server, server

I am trying to setup a QGIS WMS Server and populate it with data from my PostgreSQL database but I keep getting

```
CRITICAL Server[45873]: Error, Layer(s) geometry_lines_ff7beec1_d15f_4b53_abb3_ece34b23a625 not valid in project /home/ubuntu/data.qgz
15:22:29 WARNING Server[45873]: <ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>
```

in '/var/log/qgis/qgisserver.log' when doing a `GetProjectSettings` request.

And in '/var/log/apache2/error.log' I've got this :

```
Initializing server modules from  "/usr/lib/qgis/server"

"Checking /usr/lib/qgis/server for native services modules"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libdummy.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwcs.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwfs.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwfs3.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwms.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwmts.so"
static bool LibSecretKeyring::findPassword(const QString&, const QString&, QKeychain::JobPrivate*)
ERROR: Opening of authentication db FAILED
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
WARNING: Auth db query exec() FAILED
ERROR: Master password: FAILED to access database
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

It looks like it's a database connection issue and it's confirmed as everything worked fine when getting the layer from a file instead. It seems like the moment I switch to using my postgresql layer source it tries to use the authentication db which fails.

I keep getting the same error in my Apache logs, despite the things I've tried:

- Disabling the use of authentication db
- Exporting my qgis.db and qgis-auth.db files from QGIS Desktop to the server and setting the environment variable in '/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf' like this :
  `FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/"` (directory for qgis.db and qgis-auth.db).
  I even made sure it had the right permissions by running these commands for both files:

```
    $ sudo chown www-data:www-data ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
    $ sudo chmod 644 ~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

I have stored the username and password in the connection properties but it still won't work.
I have also set a PGSERVICEFILE like this: `SetEnv PGSERVICEFILE /home/ubuntu/.pg_service.conf`, and it seems correct as the command `psql service=myservice` is successful.

I'm running out of combinations to try now, does anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong ?

Edit:
I have tried sending the qgis-auth.db file back to my local computer to test if the authentication db would work just in case and it does so the file was not corrupted.

Edit 2: This log seemed suspicious to me :

```
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: Ini file used to initialize settings: /.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: cacheDirectory: /.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/cache/
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: maximumCacheSize: 52428800
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: Prefix  PATH: /usr
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: Plugin  PATH: /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: PkgData PATH: /usr/share/qgis
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: User DB PATH: //.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis.db
15:08:50 INFO Server[82770]: Auth DB PATH: //.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

My actual file path is "home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db", and I'm thinking the "//" in the Auth DB PATH might be the issue, but I can't find a way to change the path...